# Why is my function creating a memory leak? (C++)

Tags: c++

I have a line of code in the below program that is creating a memory leak and I am not sure why that is the case...

The line of code where the leak is being created..

```
Question* newQuestion = new Question(text, mark, answers, numAnswers, &this->operator[](qNum-1));
```

It is inserting a new node into a linked list. Do I need to delete the 'newQuestion' pointer after it is in the list? Won't that mess up my list?

The rest of the list looks like it is destroyed via the destructors when i run it through the debugger. I just can't figure out why this reference doesn't go away.

Not sure if I should post the rest of the code or not as it is a bit lengthy...I'm hoping this might just be an obvious thing that I'm missing as a C++ novice.

The method in its entirety is:

```
bool Exam::ReplaceDeleteQuestion(){
int qNum;
char repDel;
Question* temp = phead;

cout << "Which question would you like to modify? Please enter the number (1, 2, ...)" <<endl;
cin >> qNum;

for(int i = 0; i<(qNum - 1); i++){
    if(temp == NULL || temp->GetNext() == NULL){
        cout << "Please enter an element within the bounds of the linked list"<<endl;
        return true;
    }
    temp = temp->GetNext();
}

cout << "Do you want to Replace or Delete? (R = Replace, D = Delete): ";
cin >> repDel;

while(repDel != 'R' && repDel != 'r' && repDel != 'D' && repDel != 'd'){
    cout << "Try again: R = Replace, D = Delete: ";
    cin >> repDel;
}

//Set up new question and replace
if(repDel == 'r' || repDel == 'R'){

    char* questionBuffer = new char[200];
    cout << "Please enter the new question text below"<<endl;
    cin.ignore(200, '\n'); //Ignore newline character
    cin.getline(questionBuffer, 200);
    char* text = new char[strlen(questionBuffer) + 1];
    strcpy_s(text, strlen(questionBuffer)+1, questionBuffer); //Copy questionBuffer into text field
    delete[] questionBuffer; //free question buffer

    cout << "Please enter the new question mark: "<<endl;
    int mark;
    cin >> mark;
    cout << "How many answers are there now? : ";
    int numAnswers;
    cin >> numAnswers;

    Answer **answers = new Answer*[numAnswers]; //Allocate memory for the answer member

    for(int i = 0; i < numAnswers; i++){
        cout << "Please enter answer " << i+1 <<endl; //Prompt user for text
        answers[i] = new Answer(); //Create the answer
    }

    Question* newQuestion = new Question(text, mark, answers, numAnswers, &this->operator[](qNum-1));

    this->operator[](qNum-1) = *newQuestion;

    delete[] answers;
    //delete[] text;


    return true;
}
```

h file

```
  #ifndef QUESTION_H_
    #define QUESTION_H_

    #include <iostream>

    // Question.h
    class Question
{
    char* text;
    unsigned int mark;
    Answer** answers;
    unsigned int numAnswers;
    Question* pNext;
public:
    Question():text(0),mark(0),answers(0),numAnswers(0),pNext(0){};
    Question(char*, unsigned int, Answer**, unsigned int, Question*);
    Question(Question&);
    ~Question();

    Question*& GetNext()
    {
        return pNext;
    }
    Answer& operator[](unsigned int i);         //overloaded indexing
    Question& operator=(Question&);             // overloaded assignment
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Question&);    // overloaded insertion
};

#endif
```

Comment: You allocate an object on the heap (for reasons unclear). Then copy that object into whatever `this->operator[](qNum-1)` returns. The original object is never used again, and in particular is never deallocated.

Comment: Use `std::string` and `std::vector` and memory leaks will magically disappear. I didn't bother to look at your code in detail because there is too much code that is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: `Question` class should be written agnostic to any data structure. What if you want to store some questions in a stack, some in a map? Instead use `std::list<Question>`. No `new` needed any more.

Answer (score 0):

> It is inserting a new node into a linked list. Do I need to delete the `newQuestion` pointer after it is in the list?

Yes. Whatever resource you allocate with `new`/`new[]` you *must* delete it with `delete`/`delete[]`. Otherwise you will have a memory leak.

> Won't that mess up my list?

`delete`/`delete[]` calls the destructor of its operand if it's of class type. If your `Question` class deallocates the memory it internally dynamically-allocates using its destructor, then you won't get a memory leak.

But you shouldn't have to dynamically-allocate a `Question` class at all. Simply declare it as an automatic variable:

```
Question newQuestion(text, mark, answers, numAnswers, &this->operator[](qNum-1));
```

Also note that comments that point out alternatives to what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm concerned about what Question constructor does with the pointer it is passed.

Comment: @NeilKirk Indeed, it looks quite strange.